# Running pg_dump while insert queries are still running?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-dump

If I run `pg_dump` to dump a table into a SQL file, does it take a snapshot of the last row in the table, and dump all the rows up to this row?

Or does it keep dumping all the rows, even those that were inserted after `pg_dump` was ran?

A secondary question is: Is it a good idea to stop all insert queries before running `pg_dump`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will obtain a shared lock on your tables when you run the `pg_dump`. Any transactions completed **after** you run the dump will not be included. So when the dump is finished, if there are current transactions *in process* that haven't been committed, they won't be included in the dump.

There is another [`pg_dump` option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) with which it can be run:

> `--lock-wait-timeout=timeout`
>
> Do not wait forever to acquire shared table locks at the beginning of
> the dump. Instead fail if unable to lock a table within the specified
> timeout. The timeout may be specified in any of the formats accepted
> by SET statement_timeout. (Allowed formats vary depending on the
> server version you are dumping from, but an integer number of
> milliseconds is accepted by all versions.)

Comment: What if a transaction started before `pg_dump` started and finished after `pg_dump` started but before it finished?

Comment: If the transaction wasn't finished before your dump started then it won't be included

Comment: Or for that matter, what if pg_dump starts, transaction starts, transaction finishes, pg_dump finishes?

Comment: When you run pg_dump, you are dumping the databases in the state that it was in precisely when you run it - it leaves it in a consistent state. So any open transactions won't be included. And to clarify - any transactions started and completed after pg_dump is run won't be included either

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'm just clarifying because the first paragraph in your answer is a bit ambiguous. You might want to mention that pg_dump operates on a snapshot of the database which includes all transactions committed before pg_dump started or something along those lines